# How to count only same line specific column (A) is true and column (B) not empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
  | A                      | B                 | 
1 | Boolean                | number            | 
2 | TRUE                   | 0
3 | FALSE                  | 1
4 | TRUE                   | 
5 | FALSE                  | 1
- - - - - - - - -
6 | 2 COUNTIF(A2:A5,TRUE)  | ?
```

B6 How to count only same line specific column (A) is true   and column (B) not empty.

e.g  A2, A4 is true, B2 not empty B4 is empty so only count B2  = 1

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A5,TRUE,COUNTIF(...))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A5,TRUE,B2:B5,"<>")
```

See image for reference:

[image]